# Log4j2 time stamp

Tags: timestamp, log4j2

When we use AsyncLoggers (using RollingRandomAccessFile), 
is the timestamp that is written to the log file created during the invocation of log.info() method or 
is it the timestamp when the data is being written to the file?

Thank you,

Ananth

Comment: If your question has been answered, please close it.

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp is created when the LogEvent object is created, which is pretty much the same as when the `logger.info()` method is called. The timestamp is definitely *not* the time that the event is processed by the background thread.